What court positions did Abe no Yasuchika hold during the reign of Emperor Nijō?
I've been having a frustrating time researching the career of Abe no Yasuchika, who was an onmyoji (yin-yang diviner/astrologer) during the late Heian period in Japan. Searching Google mostly gives me results related to anime, light novels, or the legend of him fighting the fox spirit Tamamo no Mae. He also makes an appearance in The Tale of the Heike, but that’s still partly fictionalized, and I’m more interested in the middle portion of his life.
Here are the objective facts I’ve uncovered so far:

Japanese Wiki Corpus says he lived 1110-1183, was the great-great grandson of Abe no Yoshihira, and reached Senior Fourth Rank Upper Grade.
Wikidata adds the detail that he died on April 14, 1183 of the Gregorian calendar.
G. Cameron Hurst III’s Insei: Abdicated Sovereigns in the Politics of Late Heian Japan, 1086-1185 cites Kujō Kanezane’s diary Gyokuyō, which records a conversation where Abe no Yasuchika casts doubt on an auspicious sign observed during the reign of Emperor Nijō (1158-1165). Yasuchika’s position at the time is not included.

What I’m looking for are some basic dates for the different positions he held at court during the late Heian period. I’m particularly interested in what he was doing around 1158-1165 since he seemed critical of Emperor Nijō, and I wonder how that related to his career at the time. If there’s anything that touches on his early life, I’d be thrilled with that too, but I expect that his pre-court life wouldn’t be well recorded as he was only mid-rank nobility.
Edit: Originally I asked for sources, but I've removed that thanks to a helpful comment.

Did you try Google Scholar specifically? I think you'll at least find a few more relevant crumbs that way.

I hadn't tried Google Scholar. A quick search just now turns up a lot of the same sources as JSTOR, which mostly reference Tale of the Heike and Tamamo no Mae, but I'll investigate more.

Google Scholar turns up two very interesting sources on divination/astrology in Japan, and one of them lists his posts for 1166: Royal Attendant and Assistant Head of the Onmyōryō (Yin Yang Bureau) at Junior Fourth Rank Upper Grade. I will definitely be saving these to my research folder!

All I can recommend further is a) follow the references on the sources you have and b) if anything you're looking at is by living authors, don't be shy to try emailing them.
